# create database function is not working in postgressql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, psql

while creating the database using the `create database "databsename"` in postgresql then it does not working
below the image for the error

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there are a lot of data in `template1`, but more likely you are locked by a concurrent session. Find and terminate that session.

Comment: how to terminate that session please provide any article to rectify this

Comment: `pg_terminate_backend`